# How to make these pictures same height?

Tags: html, css

I have these 4 pictures, and I want them to be like in the picture, but I can't make them.
[This is what I need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL6Nm.png)
[This is the pictures in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MxJ6.jpg)

This is my code

```
<div class="gallery">
          <div class="flex-item-40">
            <img src="./images/coast.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="flex-item-60">
            <img src="./images/island.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="flex-item-60">
            <img src="./images/balloon.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="flex-item-40">
            <img src="./images/mountain.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .flex-item-40 {
    flex-basis: 40%;
  }

  .flex-item-60 {
    flex-basis: 60%;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Bear in mind that these images *must* have the necessary similar aspect ratios and heights to be *naturally* sized per your layout. You can't just force them to the same height without distortion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume:
First img and Fourth img: (width: 436px, height: 151px)
Second img and Third img: (width: 660px, height: 147)
Of course, these variables depend on how you "cut" the images. Because as someone said before, you will get distortions if you don't adjust the images.

```
 <div class="gallery">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="up1.png" alt="Image 1" />
      </div>
      <div class="item wider">
        <img src="up2.png" alt="Image 2" />
      </div>
      <div class="item wider">
        <img src="down1.png" alt="Image 3" />
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="down2.png" alt="Image 4" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: calc(30% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.wider {
  flex-basis: calc(70% - 10px);
}
```

Result:
[image]